# Windows 10 freezes during gameplay after update

Tags: graphics-card, freeze, windows-10-v1607

I have recently updated my PC to the Windows 10 October 4/5 update version.  The update itself took several tries to finally install properly, and since then I'll play a game and after less than half an hour it will freeze the computer completely.  Sometimes it will come back to life but usually I have to do a hard reset.

I've looked in the event logs, and some google search led me to believe it may be the RSS feed scheduled task screwing things up, but I disabled that task and the lockup is still happening.  This is not a blue screen.  The symptoms are:  all the video stops moving (including mouse cursor) and the audio stutters a certain tone that is not a distinguishable note in the music of the game.  The Windows operating system is the only major update on the PC and multiple games have caused this.  I think my next step will be to completely uninstall my video drivers and see if that helps.

Windows Version:

```
Windows 10 Pro v1607, Build 14393.222
AMD FX-6300 6-core 3.5Ghz
16.0GB RAM
NVIDIA Geforce GTX 750Ti
```

*UPDATE 10/16*
I updated the sound drivers, AMD chipset drivers, and completely cleaned out and reinstalled the video drivers according to the guide on TomsHardware.com.  Result:  the stuttering sound was different and after I did the hard reboot chkdisk automatically ran on the C: drive.

Also note:  A similar version of this problem would happen from time-to-time before the update, but at that time I could usually mash some keys (I focused on ESC and other left-hand keys) and everything would return to normal.  Now no key mashing does any good.

*More Detailed Build Info*

```
Processor (CPU)
CPU Name    AMD FX™-6300 Six-Core Processor
Threading   1 CPU - 6 Core - 6 Threads
Frequency   3495.43 MHz (17.5 * 199.74 MHz) - Uncore: 1997.4 MHz
Multiplier  Current: 17.5 / Min: 7 / Max: 20.5
Architecture    Vishera / OR-C0-Step (32 nm)
Cpuid / Ext.    F.2.0 / 15.2
IA Extensions   MMX(+), SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, SSE4A, x86-64, AES, AVX, XOP, FMA3, FMA4
Caches  L1D : 16 KB / L2 : 2048 KB / L3 : 8192 KB
Caches Assoc.   L1D : 4-way / L2 : 16-way / L3 : 64-way
TDP / Vcore 94.99 Watts / 1.28 Volts
Temperature 43.3 °C / 110 °F
Type    Retail (Stock Frequency : 3500 MHz)
Motherboard
Model   MSI 970A-G46 (MS-7693)
Socket  Socket AM3+ (942)
North Bridge    AMD RD9x0 rev 02
South Bridge    AMD SB910/950 rev 40
BIOS    American Megatrends Inc. V2.6 (10/08/2013)
Memory (RAM)
Total Size  16384 MB
Type    Dual Channel (128 bit) DDR3-SDRAM
Frequency   799 MHz - Ratio 1:4
Timings 9-9-9-24-33 (tCAS-tRC-tRP-tRAS-tCS)
Slot #1 Module  Team Group Inc. 8192 MB (DDR3-1337) - XMP 1.3 - P/N: Vulcan-1600
Slot #2 Module  Team Group Inc. 8192 MB (DDR3-1337) - XMP 1.3 - P/N: Vulcan-1600
Graphic Card (GPU)
GPU Type    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti (GM107) @ 135 MHz
GPU Brand   EVGA Corp.
GPU Specs   GM107-400 / Process: 28nm / Transistors: 1870M / Die Size: 148 mm² / TDP: 55W
GPU Units   Shader Units: 640 / Texture Units (TMU): 40 / Render Units (ROP): 16
GPU VRAM    2048 MB GDDR5 128 bit @ 405 MHz
GPU APIs    DirectX 12.0 / OpenGL 4.5 / OpenCL 1.2 / Vulkan N/A
Storage (HDD/SSD)
Model #1    Seagate ST3500410AS
Capacity #1 500 GB
Model #2    Western Digital WDC WD2500SD-01KCC0
Capacity #2 250 GB
Model #3    Corsair Force GS
Capacity #3 128 GB
Display
Screen #1   Dell Computer DELL 1907FP (DEL4015)
Screen #1 Spec  19.1 inches (48.5 cm) / 1280 x 1024 pixels @ 56-76 Hz
Screen #2   VH226 (ACI22F2)
Screen #2 Spec  21.7 inches (55.1 cm) / 1920 x 1080 pixels @ 50-76 Hz
Miscellaneous
Windows Version Microsoft Windows 10 (10.0) Professional 64-bit
Windows Subver. Build 14393
CPU-Z Version   1.77.0 (64 bit)
```

Comment: install yesterdays update KB3194798 to update to 14393.321 and look if you still get the issue.

Comment: I'll try this.  I was unaware of any new patches.

Comment: Still getting a lot of performance issues but it's slightly better than before.

Comment: press CAPS LOCK key during the freeze and look if the light on the keyboard toggles or not.

Comment: I guess I haven't specifically tested the CAPS LOCK key but CTRL+ALT+DEL didn't do anything nor did any other key mashing.

Comment: post more details about the hardware, post pictures of CPU-Z, maybe the RAM timings are bad. Also make sure the CPU/GPU don't overheat

Comment: added the updated config - not screenshot but it's from the submit feature in cpu-z

Comment: reduce the RAM speed to DDR3-1337/666MHz and not 1600/800MHz. also look for a firmware update of the Corsair Force GS SSD

Comment: reduced the RAM speed, but the ssd firmware was already up-to-date according to the Corsair SSD toolbox.

Comment: adjusting ram speed to 1337/666 did not make a difference.

Comment: there are stability issues when using SSD/HDD: http://www.winbeta.org/news/windows-10-anniversary-update-causing-freezing-issues-many-users I have no idea if this was ever fixed, maybe you run into the issue

Comment: These people seem to be having a different problem, as my PC can run all day as long as I don't try to play a game.

Comment: which PSU do you use?  also try to go back to the old Win10 Build (in settings app) and in 1511 defer the upgrades ,so that you can stay at 1511 for some time

Comment: I can no longer downgrade to previous versions before 10/17 because the time period expired.  I installed a windows update yesterday which helped a little bit, apparently, but the issue is still pretty unbearable.  PSU is Thermaltake SP-650PCBUS.  Bought it new almost exactly 1 year ago.

Comment: do a stress test for CPU/memory/GPU maybe 1 component has an issue

Comment: I will do that.  Other sites are recommending a motherboard swap because this MSI one is allegedly garbage.

Comment: Installed a new motherboard and the problem went away completely.  The MSI board in this scenario is not a good combo with the processor and Windows 10, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I got advice on TomsHardware.com and multiple forum threads on that site which suggested my Motherboard and processor, along with Windows10, were not 100% compatible.  I switched the MSI board out with an ASUS model and since then I have not even had any problems.

There were several good guides out there for swapping out a mother board and I did not even have to completely reinstall the OS.